# Can "Now or Never" quest be kept on hold?

Tags: the-witcher-3

This is my first playthrough of Witcher 3 and I know that Geralt has two potential love interests: Triss and Yenniffer. Since I have played Witcher 2, I know about Triss and this game has been pushing me in to TeamTriss too... However I have not started any missions with Yenniffer and so I don't know who/how she is?

Basically, I know that at the end of "Now or Never" quest, I have a chance to propose to Triss or risk leaving her forever with Yenniffer as the significant other. However it's too early for me to make the choice. I need to know about Yenniffer more before choosing between her and Triss.

So the question is: *can I skip playing "Now or Never" (not met Triss yet) until I finish all the future Yenniffer questlines and then continue it or is it a "time-sensitive" quest that cannot be started if I'm too late*?

Reasons for thinking this quest is "time-sensitive":

- Whole town is hunting for mages suddenly
- Heard Geralt saying there's a group of witch-hunters before Triss' house

Comment: To pick up Triss, you pretty much need to throw yourself at her over the course of 4(?) events. To avoid picking up Yenniffer, you need to avoid "The Last Wish" or be an awe inspiring jerk. Make of that what you will

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This quest must be done before you start the "Isle of Mists" quest, which is quite a bit later in the main story line. I don't think there are any quests which are time sensitive.

There are numerous interactions with Yen in the Skellige and Kaer Morhen based quests before you get to the Isle of Mists.

Comment: So I can skip this quest right? It's not a time-sensitive quest where skipping it for long might fail the quest?

Comment: I don't think there are any time sensitve quests at all, just ones that fail if you do some other quest.

Comment: This was the confirmation that I needed. Since the city is closed and witch hunters were searching for mages, I thought this quest might be time-sensitive

Comment: More like "Now or Whenever", then.